# ASP.NET C# - running a .exe process and reloading the page when it's done

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I'm building an application to configure some software components from a web GUI.

For one of my configuration components, I'm loading an executable to pick an sftp folder. This sftp path is stored together with other variables in a json file, which is then displayed in the input fields.

[image: Executable launched on button press]

The cshtml code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="browseSftp()">Select SFTP folder</button>

function browseSftp() {
    window.$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/BackupConfiguration?handler=BrowseSftp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                window.$('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            autoBackup: $('input[name="FormData.autoBackup"]:checked').val(),
            backupTime: $('#FormData_backupTime').val(),
            keepAllBackups: $('input[name="FormData.keepAllBackups"]:checked').val(),
            backupsKept: $('#FormData_backupsKept').val(),
            hostName: $('#FormData_hostName').val(),
            hostKey: $('#FormData_hostKey').val(),
            port: $('#FormData_port').val(),
            username: $('#FormData_username').val(),
            password: $('#FormData_password').val(),
            remoteFolder: $('#FormData_remoteFolder').val(),
            localFolder: $('#FormData_localFolder').val(),
            isLocal: $('input[name="FormData.isLocal"]:checked').val(),
        }),
        success: function (response) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
};
```

in my cshtml.cs code:

```
public void OnPostBrowseSftp([FromBody] FormData formData)
{
    //string[] args = { FormData.autoBackup, FormData.backupTime, FormData.keepAllBackups, FormData.backupsKept, FormData.hostName, FormData.hostKey, FormData.port, FormData.username, FormData.password, FormData.remoteFolder, FormData.localFolder, "TRUE" };

    string[] args = {FormData.hostName,  FormData.username, FormData.password};
    if(formData.autoBackup == null)
    {
        formData.autoBackup = "false";
    }
    if(formData.keepAllBackups == null)
    {
        formData.keepAllBackups = "false";
    }

   
   var process =  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(_browseSftpScript, formData.hostName + " " + formData.username + " " + formData.password + " " + formData.autoBackup + " " + formData.backupTime + " " + formData.keepAllBackups + " " + formData.backupsKept + " " + formData.port + " " + formData.isLocal + " "  + _jsonPath);
       process.WaitForExit();
       Response.Redirect("/backupConfiguration");
}
```

Just re initializing the page with the onGet function would cause the fields to be populated, but somehow this is not done, only if I manually select another page and go back it's done:

```
public void OnGet()
{
    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString(SettingName) == null || HttpContext.Session.GetString(SettingName) != "AlreadyLoaded")
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString(SettingName, "AlreadyLoaded");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(_systemSettingJsonPath))
        {
            FormData = SettingsService.GetData<FormData>(_systemSettingJsonPath);
            SettingsService.SaveData(FormData, _jsonPath);
        }
        else
        {
            FormData = SettingsService.GetData<FormData>(_jsonPath);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        FormData = SettingsService.GetData<FormData>(_jsonPath);
    }

}
```

If I have a look at my logs, I think it's because the onGet function is called before the browseSftp request is finished.

```
2021-11-25 17:31:22.922 +01:00 [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware] [INF] Executed endpoint '/BackupConfiguration'
2021-11-25 17:31:22.922 +01:00 [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics] [INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/BackupConfiguration?handler=BrowseSftp application/json;+charset=UTF-8 228 - 200 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 705431.7372ms
```

I would expect that this would cause the process to be finished, and therefore the request to be done:

```
       process.WaitForExit();
       Response.Redirect("/backupConfiguration");
```

So to put it short, my goal is to trigger a reload of the page, after the process is finished.

Thanks for your input on this !

Comment: Wouldn't a bidirectional communication protocol like WebSockets be better suited here? That way you don't need to reload the page.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, if the application takes too long to close, the request will time out.

Comment: With websocket, do you mean to directly get the json data from the executable as a stream ?